# Append memory stream with data byte to download in csv

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, memorystream

I am trying to append the memory stream in a loop and then pass it to the HTTPResponseMessage as a csv file, however when i download the file, no data is displayed.

```
 var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                     search = GetSearch(searchResultParam);
                    csvContent = GetCsvForSearchResult(search);
                    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                
            }
           

            string fileName = "Review" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + ".csv";
            var result = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(stream)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
```

But if I write it directly to the memory stream, the data is being downloaded.

```
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                     search = GetSearch(searchResultParam);
                    csvContent = GetCsvForSearchResult(search);
                    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent);
                    stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data); 

            }


            string fileName = "Review" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + ".csv";
            var result = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(stream)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
```

Comment: Did you try seeking back to the start after adding data? `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: thank you so much it did work, however the data are not in order and the bytes length is added to one of the rows.

Comment: In your working example where you don't use Stream.Write, you reassign the stream on each iteration of the for loop, so it's not 100% clear to me what your desired output should be. Can you please clarify?

Comment: In the working example where I don't use Stream.Write, I was testing the case, I want all the data retrieved to be appended in the memory stream. using stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); solved the issue and data was visible in the downloaded file, however all the data weren't retrieved and there was issue in the appended data. I tried using other enums of SeekOrigin too, but no luck

Comment: I'm guessing that you put the seek within the loop, if you pull it out to just after the end of the for loop I suspect it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seek the stream to the start before letting the client consume it

```cs
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                     search = GetSearch(searchResultParam);
                    csvContent = GetCsvForSearchResult(search);
                    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                
            }
            // will make the reads start at the beginning 
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           
            string fileName = "Review" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + ".csv";
            var result = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(stream)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
```

Comment: Then you need to split `GetCsvForSearchResult(search)` into two methods one that returns the header that you call once. And one that returns the data that you loop over